# org.jboss.byteman.agent.Transformer : invalid text outside of RULE/ENDRULE at line 1 in script

Tags: java, jboss, byteman

I am configuring byteman in my jboss application but I am getting this error:
org.jboss.byteman.agent.Transformer : invalid text outside of RULE/ENDRULE at line 1 in script

I checked the script syntaxis and is valid, I am using the example from the jboss solution article:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/650163

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.